# How do I annotate a function that takes AnyStr with a str default value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

I wish to type-annotate a function that takes an `AnyStr` argument that defaults to a `str` and also returns an `AnyStr` of the same type.  However, if I write this:

```
from typing import AnyStr

def func(s: AnyStr = ".") -> AnyStr:
    return s
```

then mypy fails with "`Incompatible default for argument "s" (default has type "str", argument has type "bytes")`".

I also tried splitting the code into a `.py` and `.pyi` file like so:

`.py` file:

```
def func(s = "."):
    return s
```

`.pyi` file:

```
from typing import AnyStr

def func(s: AnyStr = ...) -> AnyStr:
    ...
```

... but I must be invoking mypy wrong, because it fails to type-check the invocations of `func`; e.g., if I add `func(42)` to the `.py` file, mypy doesn't complain.

What is the correct way to annotate my function and get the code to be completely type-checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `None` as the default value, then inside the function use two casts: one to replace `None` with "." cast as an `Optional[AnyStr]`, and one to cast the return value as an `AnyStr`.

```
def func(s : AnyStr = None) -> AnyStr:
    if s is None:
        s = cast(Optional[AnyStr], ".")
    return cast(AnyStr, s)
```

---

EDIT: My original answer fails, as the type check ignores the concrete implementation:

One possibility is to use `overload` to enumerate the two cases covered by `AnyStr`:

```
from typing import overload


@overload
def func(s: str = ".") -> str:
    pass


@overload
def func(s: bytes) -> bytes:
    pass


def func(s):
    return s
```

Comment: But then the actual implementation of `func` isn't type-checked.  If I replace the body with `return s < 42`, mypy doesn't error.

Comment: For the record (and anyone who stumbles upon this question), although your revised answer works with mypy out of the box, I prefer to set `--no-implicit-optional`, which makes mypy reject the code.  With that option, I need to change the annotation of `s` in the function arguments to `s: Optional[AnyStr] = None`, and I also had to remove the `Optional` from the first cast so that my actual code would pass type-checking.

Answer (score 1):

This case was discussed [here](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3737). Guido's answer in particular:

> I think the problem here is that in general, e.g. if there are other parameters also using `_T` in their type, the default value won't work. Since this is the only parameter, you could say that this is overly restrictive, and if there are no parameters, the return type should just be determined by that default value (in your simplified example, you'd want it to return `int`). But I'm not so keen on doing that, since it breaks as soon as another generic parameter is used.

Based on that thread, you can use the following workaround:

```
from typing import AnyStr, overload


@overload
def func() -> str: ...

@overload
def func(s: AnyStr) -> AnyStr: ...

def func(s = "."):  # unchecked implementation
    return func_internal(s)

def func_internal(s: AnyStr) -> AnyStr:
    # a checked complicated body moved here
    return s
```

Comment: This isn't that different from my original answer, which fails to ensure that a type-correct argument to `func` is used in a type-correct fashion. Replace `foo_internal(s)` with `foo_internal(s) < 42`, and `mypy` continues to accept it.

Comment: I agree that the code in an unchecked function should be kept to a minimum, and this is still a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you want:

```
@overload
def func(s: str=...) -> str: ...   
@overload
def func(s: bytes) -> bytes: ...
@overload
def func(s: None) -> str: ...    

def func(s="."):
    return s


r1 = func()
reveal_type(r1)
r2 = func("1")
reveal_type(r2)
r3 = func(b"1")
reveal_type(r3)

Mypy: The stdout of the command line is:
note: Revealed type is 'builtins.str'
note: Revealed type is 'builtins.str'
note: Revealed type is 'builtins.bytes'
```